# How to disable webcam of a laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, webcam, camera

In Windows and Ubuntu, how to disable build-in webcam of a laptop, so that no app can use it? In some laptops there is webcam disabling option in BIOS.But not available in all.So, there any software of build-in option/tools in OS by which webcam can be fully disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, you simply go in the `Administrative tools > Computer management > Device manger` and find your webcam in the list, usually under the USB controllers. You can right click on it and disable it from there.

In Linux, one answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166809/how-can-i-disable-my-webcam).

Comment: You could also use a sticky note/post it. I have one over my webcam (I don't use it anyways). The issue with a "fix" (like Device Manager) is that someone could write a [script to reactivate the driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229918/device-enable-disable-script) and maliciously use your webcam.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the low tech approach:

[image]

Comment: I used it for sometimes, but it looks odd.

Comment: Yes it looks odd, but if you are worried someone might be spying on you, then it is the only solution, since if they can hack your machine to see the camera output, they can likely hack it to turn the camera back on after you disabled it.